# How to pass parameter for bundled file through dynamic config file or (dynamic file) in react js using parcel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, parceljs

I have created on basic microservice application. I created it like CDN link. I need the user to send the authentication-related details. but I don't want to pass the values through the data attribute or script tag.

After filling in all the parameter values, I expect to create a one-time form. this form value should update in separate files, I wanted to use this file value inside my bundle *js* file. It's a dynamic process this form values get changing based on the user.

I want to use outside dynamic file variable or objects inside bundled *js* file (CDN link)

Is it possible to get value from outside source for my bundle file (CDN link) in react?

For example:
I have bundled my entire project as **microservice** and deployed in **github** in below url

`https://gaurav-08-dev.github.io/test2/index.js`

I have shared my code, how I am embedding this script inside my react application.

```
const bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

const scriptTag = document.createElement("script")
scriptTag.id = "ihtml";
scriptTag.src = 'https://gaurav-08-dev.github.io/test2/index.js';
bodyElement.append(scriptTag);
```

Now the issue is wanting to pass properties(props or argument) from React application to the **microservice**, but I do not want to pass the props through `data-attributes` in tags.

Can anyone please help me to find a solution to pass argument?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: details are edited